# PHP Switch using Form Promo Code - In Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I have a simple form. I need different promo codes to redirect you to different pages. Example: 1234 will send you to example.com. 2323 will send you to newwebsite.com. I understand how to do this using a form and php, but I need the client to be able to enter the codes and redirects themselves. There didn't seem to be any plugins that did what I need. I use gravity forms, but that would still require the client to edit the template file. Here is my code:

```
    <form action="switch.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="codes" id="codes" />
    <input type="submit" /> 

    <?php $i = $_POST; ?>
    <?php switch($_POST['codes']) {
        case "1234":
             header("Location: http://www.myfoursquare.net/archives");
            break;
        case "2222":
           header("Location: http://www.myfoursquare.net/archives");
            break;
        case "3333":
              header("Location: http://www.myfoursquare.net/archives");
            break;
            }
    ?></form>
```

This works as intended. Not sure how to make this wordpress friendly for the client.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [Meta Box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) that [only shows up when a given Page Template](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18122/toggle-admin-metabox-based-upon-chosen-page-template) is selected. In it, some repeatable fields where the user enters a series of *Code* + *Redirect URL*.

Then, in the template page, it would be similar to:

```
# Gets the array of CODE/URL pairs
$all_codes = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'all_codes', true );
# Get the URL correspondent to the posted 'codes'
$redirect = $all_codes[ $_POST['codes'] ];
# Do the redirect
header("Location: $redirect");
```

The structure of `$all_codes` really depends on how the meta box is implemented.
[This search query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Plugin%20Name:%22%20%2badd_meta_boxes%20is:a) has many examples of Meta Boxes.
And [this other](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2badd_meta_boxes%20%2brepeatable) how to deal with repeatable fields.

The plugin [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) automates all this and the repeatable feature is a premium add-on. [Custom Content Type Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-content-type-manager/) has the feature built-in.

<sub>PS: it's important to [*always validate and sanitize*](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/data-sanitization-and-validation-with-wordpress/) all user input</sub>

Comment: This looks so much easier than what I was trying just attempting (a bunch of different custom fields on a page). If I use the Custom Content Type Manager repeatable fields, can you advise how that fits in. Are there two separate text boxes...one for code and one for url?

Comment: You'd really have to play with it to get it right. Do you have a local installation for testing? But the normal is: 1) add repeatable field 2) configure sub-fields 3) check the plugin documentation on how to extract the data

Comment: I edited my code above if it's possible for you to hopefully connect the dots.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not your intention, but this turns into a [Chameleon Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478). If your initial issue is solved, you should open a [new Q](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). A Q&A site does not work with this kind of *follow-up* support.

Comment: Sorry bout that. I opened a new question in the wordpress.stackexchange. Thanks for your direction though.

Comment: Cool that you found WPSE ;) Hint: use an unified account for all [se] network.